# Opening a file with "less" causes notify-send to send a message

Tags: gnome, notify-send, less

In my development environment, we have some helper scripts that wrap certain commands (like maven or docker), and then use `notify-send` to send a notification if the commands fail.  After running a particular build that failed, every time that I open a file using `less`, that build failed notification pops up.

Any ideas what's going on there?  (I realize I have no code/files to be able to show what my scripts look like, and no way to reproduce it, but any ideas would be appreciated)

Update based on comments:
`type -a less` shows `less is /usr/bin/less`
and
`echo $LESS` is empty.

Comment: Look at `type -a less` to see if it's an alias or a function. Look at `echo $LESS`, and read `man less`.

Comment: `type -a less` = `less is /usr/bin/less`  

`echo $LESS` = empty

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story.